# Implement counter prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm developing a board game in PROLOG and in order to make the interface more enjoyable for the user, I decided to add a grid with the coordinates (0->4) as shown below:

```
    0 1 2 3 4
    ---------
0 | x x x x x
1 | x o x o o
2 | o x o x x
3 | x x o o o
4 | o x x x o
```

After developing some code, I came across with an issue regarding the counter for the vertical coordinates. The predicate stops right after I implement the counter `Index is Index + 1`, as shown below:

```
printGrid :- %Only prints the horizontal grid
        write('\t'), write(0), write('   '), write(1), write('   '), write(2), write('   '), write(3), write('   '), write(4), nl,
        write('\t'), write('------------------'), nl.     

printBoard([Head|Tail]) :-
        Index = 0,
        Index is Index + 1,
        % STOPS HERE ------------
        write('    '), write(Index), write('  |'), write(' '),
        printRow(Head),
        printBoard(Tail).
printBoard([]).

printRow([Head|Tail]) :-
        write(Head),
        write('  '),
        printRow(Tail).
printRow([]) :- nl.
```

I'm aware the counter will reset to 0 every time recursion is called, thus I don't really know how to set the Index to 0 just about once and go from there. Any tips on how to solve both of the issues?

Comment: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~pjh/prolog_course/md5/md5_accumulators.html look at the first example. Do you need something similar?

Comment: A question still remains tho, why did the computation stop after that line of code? (See above)

Comment: Because `I is I + 1` will always fail, since no number is equal to itself plus 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined the link which @Otrebor provided and I came up with a fine solution. I forgot the "little" detail that when bound, a variable can't be changed, thus I added an extra one. Here's how it looks:

```
printBoard([], _).
printBoard([Head|Tail], Counter) :-
        Index is Counter + 1,
        write('    '), write(Index), write('  |'), write(' '),
        printRow(Head),
        printBoard(Tail, Index).

main :- printBoard(Board, 0).
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the value of a variable that has been already *bound*. You need to use a new variable, for example, `I1 is I + 1`, or maybe `succ(I, I1)`.

Another thing you can do if you want to anyway use the side effect (printing in your case), is to put `between` in a `forall` loop:

```
?- forall(between(0, 4, X), format('~d~n', [X])).
0
1
2
3
4
true.
```

You can of course have nested `forall`s:

```
?- forall(between(0, 5, X),
       (   forall(between(0, 4, Y),
               format('~d-~d ', [X,Y])),
           format('~n')
       )).
0-0 0-1 0-2 0-3 0-4 
1-0 1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4 
2-0 2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4 
3-0 3-1 3-2 3-3 3-4 
4-0 4-1 4-2 4-3 4-4 
5-0 5-1 5-2 5-3 5-4 
true.
```

The way to enumerate the members of a list, then, would be to use `nth0`, for example,

```
?- forall(nth0(N, [a,b,c,d], E), format('~d-~a~n', [N,E])).
0-a
1-b
2-c
3-d
true.
```

Or, if you don't need the element (when you are just marking the columns:

```
?- length([a,b,c,d], Len),
   Last is Len - 1,
   forall(between(0, Last, X), format('~d~n', [X])).
0
1
2
3
Len = 4,
Last = 3.
```

Or ignoring the element when you are using `nth0`:

```
?- forall(nth0(N, [a,b,c,d], _), format('~d~n', [N])).
0
1
2
3
true.
```

There are other predicates that can offer similar functionality, depending on what exactly your goal is. See `findall` and `maplist`, for example.

But of course you can do the recursion yourself, if you remember to do the `I1 is I + 1`.

Comment: I appreciate and understand your answer, but I was looking for a simpler solution, as similar to c/c++ as it could get.

Comment: @Khabz :) you are welcome. It is a matter of taste, and your solution is actually much closer to Prolog, while what I am showing here is just emulating a for loop in the C/C++ style. You would never write a recursive function to just enumerate elements of an array in C, would you ;)

Comment: Hell no! I thought I'd get rid of this kind of langs after learning Scheme, but I guess my college really enjoys teaching these non intuitive prog langs :(

Comment: @Khabz I agree, both C and C++ can be really difficult sometimes. But while Prolog or Scheme are intuitive and the syntax clearer, some low-level algorithms are better implemented in C or C++. This is why there is so much research into functional languages.