# Adding numbers in Prolog and unifying it with same variable

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a recursive definition which runs for say 4 times giving new value to `X1` every time,and the final value of `A1` should be sum of all the `X1`.(That is I want to implement `A1=A1+X1` where `X1` gets new values after every recursive call)

```
add(A1,X1,L1,L):-
   L1 is L+1,
   A1 is A1+X1.

Sum(A1,L):-
   nth1(L,[1,2,4,5],X1),
   add(A1,X1,L1,L),
   (  L1<=4 ->Sum(A1,L1)
   ;  write('')
   ).
```

Comment: It is not possible in Prolog, when a variable is unified, you can't change its value.

Comment: What are the alternatives then,I mean how can I find the sum then?

Comment: @joel76 I want to continuously find the sum of A=A+A1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement counter prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733040/implement-counter-prolog)

Comment: In the third line of the code listing, you are doing it again: `A1 is A1+X1`. If you want to have 3 input and 2 output arguments, your predicate will have to have 5 arguments, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling looking at your code and the names you use for variables, that you think that variables are somehow always global. And you don't have to "declare" or "instantiate" a number with `N is 1`. So your code could be:

```
main :-
    add(2, 3).

add(X, Y) :-
    sum(X, Y, Sum), write(Sum), /* X is Sum */ write(X), nl.

sum(X, Y, Sum) :-
    Sum is X + Y.
```

Saying `X is Sum` means in this case that `X` and `Sum` must be the same number.

Now, if you wanted to actually add two things together and keep the new sum, you would have to use a new variable for it, since this is how variables work:

```
add(X, Y) :-
    sum(X, Y, Sum), write(Sum),
    nl,
    sum(Sum, X, X1), write(X1),
    nl.
```

Comment: Suppose I have a recursive definition which runs for say 5 times giving new value to `X1` every time,and the final value of `A1` should be sum of all the `X1`.(That is I want to implement `A1=A1+X1` where`X1` gets new values after every recursive call)

Comment: @Noober You will need to use a new variable and pass that to the recursive call. Edit your question to show what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Variables, once bound to a value (unified) **cease to be variable**. They become an immutable object.

However, to accomplish what you want (as I understand your problem statement), you can say something like this:

```
sum(A,X,1,S) :-    % one iteration, and we're done. Just compute the sum of A+X.
  S is A+X .       % - just compute the sum of A+X and unify it with S.
sum(A,X,N,S) :-    % otherwise...
  N > 1 ,          % - so long as N > 1 ,
  N1 is N-1 ,      % - decrement N
  A1 is A+X ,      % - compute a new A, the sum of the current A+X
  sum(A1,X,N1,S) . % - and recurse down, passing the new values.
```